# В Unity отрабатывает деактивированный в инспекторе, но висящий на объекте скрипт

Tags: unity3d

Чтобы отключить, можно только удалить?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Visor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string tagWall = "Wall";
    public string tagTarget = "Enemy";
    public GameObject agent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (agent == null)
            agent = gameObject;
        print("indexer");
    }



    public void OnTriggerStay(Collider coll)
    {
        string tag = coll.gameObject.tag;
        if (!tag.Equals(tagTarget))
            return;
        GameObject target = coll.gameObject;
        Vector3 agentPos = agent.transform.position;
        Vector3 targetPos = target.transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = targetPos - agentPos;
        float length = direction.magnitude;
        direction.Normalize();
        Ray ray = new Ray(agentPos, direction);
        RaycastHit[] hits;
        hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, length);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject hitObj;
            hitObj = hits[i].collider.gameObject;
            tag = hitObj.tag;
            if (tag.Equals(tagWall))
                return;
        }
        // TODO
        // target is visible code your behaviour below
        /*
        //вариант поведения с Arrive/Leave:
        GetComponent<Face>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<Arrive>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<Leave>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<Wander>().enabled = false;
        */
        //вариант поведения с pursue:
        GetComponent<Face>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<Pursue>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<Wander>().enabled = false;
    }
    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider coll)
    {
        /*
        //вариант поведения с Arrive/Leave:
        GetComponent<Face>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Arrive>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Leave>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Wander>().enabled = true;
        */
        //вариант поведения с pursue:
        //if (coll.name == "Player")
        //{
            GetComponent<Face>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Pursue>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Wander>().enabled = true;
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: добавь код  наглядно демонстрирующий проблему и например скрин иерархии. и опиши что именно происходит, почему ты решил, что он работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выключение скрипта останавливает только "периодические" методы - `Update`, `LateUpdate`, `FixedUpdate`. А вот **события** (те, что начинаются с "On..."), вызываемые системой коллизии все равно остаются активными.

Обычно и чаще всего для написания логики на объект, когда тот в триггере пишут так:

- Заводят булевый флаг.
- На `OnTriggerEnter` делают его значение `true`, на `OnTriggerExit` — `false`.
- Пока флаг `true` — делать действия. Или наоборот, если флаг `false` — больше ничего не делать (`if (!inTrigger) return;`)

Пример:

```
bool inTrigger = false;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    inTrigger = true;
    // other code
}

 void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){
    inTrigger = false;
    // other code
 }

 void Update(){
    if (inTrigger){
        // OnTriggerStay code
        MySuperMethodWhileStayInTrigger();
    }
    // other code
 }

void MySuperMethodWhileStayInTrigger() {
    // ...
}
```

Единственное, может случиться так, что в триггер может влететь одновременно несколько объектов и тогда `OnTriggerExit` сработает только на первом вылетевшем. Поэтому иногда делают еще вот так:

```
int inTrigger = 0;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    inTrigger++;
   // other code
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){
    inTrigger--;
    // other code
}

void Update(){
    if (inTrigger > 0){
        // OnTriggerStay code
        MySuperMethodWhileStayInTrigger();
    }
}

void MySuperMethodWhileStayInTrigger() {
    // ...
}

// other code
```

То есть считают "треггернутость". И если не равно 0, значит внутри кто-то есть.