# Unity проверка на соприкосновение с триггером

Tags: c#, unity3d, триггер

Добрый вечер!

Возникла необходимость в Unity на C# написать метод, который определяет,  касается объект чего-нибудь (проверка на вхождение триггера), или нет и возвращает `true` или `false` соответственно.

Это должно быть чем-то вроде этого:

```
bool GetTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col){

    if(col == null)

        return false;

    else

        return true;

}
```

...Только должно работать)
Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737440/191482

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оно так не работает:

Посмотрите [доки](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html). Там есть события на соприкосновение тригеров. Можете в этих событиях добавлять коллайдеры в список:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
     // здесь вы можете в список куда-то добавить коллайдер
 }

 void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
     // удалить из списка
 }
```

А в своём методе проверять потом, есть ли переданный коллайдер в списке столкнувшийся:

```
bool GetTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col){
     // здесь проверяете, есть ли в списке столкнувшихся коллайдеров он
     // возвращаете true, если есть, false, если нету в списке
     return true;
}
```

Comment: всё-таки OnTriggerEnter и OnTriggerEnter2D чуть разные)